# How to call listview with confirmation dialog?

Tags: java, android

I want to show confirmation dialog box to user that when user click on yes button open listview to select.

Comment: I have a temp list im my app.when user drag every comment in temp list to the right app show confirm box to user for save it to some list.I want show list view to give the name of groups to user then users choose their category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link..............................

```
http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/alert-dialog-dialog-with-item-list.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this

```
 Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
            build.setTitle("Title name");
            build.setMessage("?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //IF yes button pressed then write here
                    }
                   dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            build.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```